# serialize doesn't include hidden fields

Tags: jquery, serialization

I run serialize on a form, where on of the fields is hidden - and it's a very important field, which should be posted. Is there any way to easily serialize it through jQuery or should I write my own function?

Comment: `serialize` should include hidden fields.  Can we see the markup and script?

Comment: The only fields I can think of that should not be included would be disabled fields.

Comment: Serialize does include hidden fields, but not disabled ones.
++ on wanting to see the markup and script.

Comment: You need a `name` attribute, I would guess.

Comment: I did everything right and still it didn't work. Then I investigated deeper and found, that it's the 3rd party autocomplete module, that failed. It just didn't feel the hidden field. The jQuery function worked well.

Thank a lot for you help.

Comment: Check you've not got a duplicate field name - like the same form control field twice, this will cause it to fail too

Answer (score 140, accepted):

[Serialize](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize) *does* include all enabled `input` elements **with a `name` attribute**.

Comment: why do jquery use name attribute to serialize a form, instead of using id attribute?

Comment: @frabiacca Because the `name` attribute is the identifier for POST data http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp

Comment: I have problems with checkboxed which have style/css display:none. They are not picked up.

Comment: @Bandpay [Yes they are](http://jsfiddle.net/s6VvS/1/). You have a different problem.

Comment: Cool. Easy thing to forget!

Comment: @BabakBandpay Serialize only returns checked values.

Comment: File input elements are not included even if they have a name.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe combining the two in a single selector would work?

```
$(":input,:hidden").serialize();
```

edit: I just tried the above and it worked. but, $("form").serialize(); should automatically take all inputs as others have mentioned.

Comment: It does only if it has a name attribute which ends up being the key of the object.

Answer (score 2):

You need set the name attribute and check the **disabled** attribute! The disabled field also not serialized.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this problem myself, and hacked out a solution.

The problem has to do with the way JQuery picks up hidden html information. It will not pick up the TEXT of a hidden field as its value, you must use the value= property.

To set it in JQUERY use `$(field).val(yourvalue);`

Answer (score 0):

you should add name to all elements for serialize function to work properly

Answer (score -6):

I had this problem as well.  Out of habit I close my input fields with />.  I found that hidden input does not work when closed this way.

```
<input type="hidden" name="someName" value="someValue" />
```

does not work.

```
<input type="hidden" name="someName" value="someValue" >
```

does work.

Comment: Incorrect. It has nothing to do with what you mention.